# Angular 2 API Interceptor makes call twice when retrying

Tags: angular, api, post, interceptor

I have an api interceptor set up to catch if the users token is invalid and if so to get a new token and retry the call it looks like this:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { empty, Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { UserService } from "./user.service";
import { catchError, switchMap, finalize, tap, map, delay } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AlertService } from "./alert.service";
import { resetStores } from "@datorama/akita";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { UserStore } from "../stores/user.store";
import { LoadingServiceService } from "../services/loading-service.service";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class ApiInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    updatingToken: boolean = false;
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private auth: AngularFireAuth,
        private userStore: UserStore,
        private loadingService: LoadingServiceService
    ) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.loadingService.setLoading(true);
        if (req.url.includes("auth")) {
            return next.handle(req).pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    this.loadingService.setLoading(false);
                })
            );
        }
        return next.handle(this.cloneRequest(req)).pipe(
            catchError((error: any) => {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
                        case 401:
                            return this.handle401Response(req, next);

                        default:
                            return throwError(error);
                    }
                }
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                this.loadingService.setLoading(false);
            })
        );
    }

    handle401Response(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        console.log("handling 401");
        if (this.updatingToken) {
            if (!this.userService.get()) {
                return throwError("no user");
            }
        }

        this.updatingToken = true;
        if (this.checkExpiration()) {
            return throwError("Expired User");
        }
        return this.auth.idTokenResult.pipe(
            switchMap((newToken: any) => {
                if (newToken) {
                    var expDateTime = new Date(newToken.expirationTime).getHours() + 12;
                    var expDate = new Date(newToken.expirationTime).setHours(expDateTime);
                    this.userStore.update({
                        token: {
                            authToken: newToken.token,
                            expirationTime: new Date(newToken.expirationTime),
                            logOutTime: new Date(expDate)
                        }
                    });
                    return next.handle(this.cloneRequest(req)).pipe(
                        finalize(() => {
                            window.location.reload();
                            this.loadingService.setLoading(false);
                        })
                    );
                }
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                this.userService.logout();
                return throwError(error);
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                this.updatingToken = false;
            })
        );
    }

    cloneRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
        console.log(req);
        // Clone the request to add the new header
        const user = this.userService.get();
        return req.clone({
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: user.token.authToken
            })
        });
    }

    checkExpiration() {
        const user = this.userService.get();
        if (new Date(user.token.logOutTime) < new Date()) {
            this.alertService.createInactivityAlert();
            resetStores();
            this.router.navigate(["login"]);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The interceptor works as should get me a new token but it makes the call twice, which isnt a huge issue for GET calls but for POST calls any data thats is being inserted is now inserting twice. Any reason this is happening? Below is my console showing that the call gets a 401 error, hits the handle 401 error and the call (/addPlayer) gets made twice.

[image: Console of call being made twice]

Comment: it's really hard to say from the provided code. `this.auth.idTokenResult` might be emitting several values, try adding `take(1)`. also you could add a bunch of `console.log`s to see which observable is causing the duplication

Comment: Try add a if/else...`if (req.url.includes("auth")) {...} else {...}`

Comment: The ```this.auth.idTokenResult``` is from firebase to get a new token. If I added a take(1) where would it be, in the handle401?

Comment: yeah, the very first operator `this.auth.idTokenResult.pipe(take(1), swichMap(.... )`

Comment: That looks like it worked, thanks! If you want make an answer and ill mark it.